# "Parallel" Sockets in python

Tags: python, file, sockets, networking, udp

this is my UDP-Server very according to the UDP-Server-Example from the python-wiki:

```
# ----- receiver.py -----

#!/usr/bin/env python

from socket import *
import sys
import select

host="192.168.88.51"
port = 1337
s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host,port))

addr = (host,port)
buf=128

data,addr = s.recvfrom(buf)
print "Received File:"
f = open("out.jpg",'wb')

data, addr = s.recvfrom(buf)
try:
    while(data):
        f.write(data)
        s.settimeout(1)
        data,addr = s.recvfrom(buf)
except timeout:
    f.close()
    s.close()
    print "File Downloaded"
```

This code works fine and I'm able to receive ONE file at a time. But I have multiple clients and I'd like to receive every file coming in, so every time a new connection is established (from one certain IP).
Any suggestions?

Comment: Just FYI: I know that "out.jpg" is a constant and then should be replaced eg by the IP of the client.

Comment: Perhaps experiment with threads? Also, how would you differentiate between files and multiple "connections" if you only have a single socket? Perhaps think about some kind of *protocol* instead of just sending raw data?

Comment: Yes, if I had the choice I would have taken TCP and sockets. But I don't have that choice, I'm bound to the way clients send their data.

Comment: Do you have *any* control over the clients? If not then all you can use is the `addr` returned by `recvfrom` to distinguish between clients. Now think about how you can use it, for example with a dictionary, to be able to write to multiple files.

Comment: I do have "some" control over the clients, it's Arduinos sending UDP-data. But the capabilities are very limited. But anyways, do you know how to solve a dictionary-like service in python?

Comment: Start a new thread as soon as your `recvfrom` unblocks, i.e., when a new client is connected. This thread should handle the connection with the client. Also, you should maybe use a while loop to keep listening for other connections.

Comment: That sounds logical. Could you give an example of how to actually write that in python as I'm probably not experienced enough? I'd like to use it as an answer for this whole question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want an asynchronous server, it's better to not write things from scratch with `sockets`. Instead, use packages like `asyncio` or `Twisted`.

Coming to your problem, it's more convenient to go with a TCP-focused socket, therefore you should use `SOCK_STREAM` instead of the UDP type `SOCK_DGRAM`.

First, define a function for downloading:

```
def get_file(s):
    s.settimeout(1)
    with open("out.jpg",'wb') as f:
        data, addr = s.recv(buf)
        try:
            while(data):
                f.write(data)
                data, addr = s.recv(buf)
        except timeout:
            print "File Downloaded"
```

After setting up the constants (hostname, port number and so on), do something like the following (and do `from threading import Thread` first!):

```
s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host,port))
while True:
    print "Waiting for connection..."
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(buf)
    print "... connection from:", addr
    Thread(target=get_file, args=(s,)).start()  #starts a new thread for file download, addr acts like a filename
```

Comment: @goetzmoritz Have a look.

Comment: @goetzmoritz What output are you getting?

Comment: Nothing, just "Waiting for  connection...". Port and Host are correct, unchanged.

Comment: @goetzmoritz Hmmm... what client are you using to connect? Within the client code, you need to write a line like `client_socket.connect(server_addr)`.

Comment: Arduino with Ethercard-Library. It only supports UDP for this application. Probably this is the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153105/discussion-between-sam-chats-and-goetzmoritz).